# Dev environment for multiple server setup - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, development-environment

This is my first time building out something with multiple servers. I wanted to know if anyone could point me towards a guide for setting up a dev environment (windows) for a backend that will be set up on multiple servers ie one server for the API, one for another set of processes (ie file compression) and one for everything else.

Again, just trying to figure out if it's possible to set up a dev environment to test out the system on my local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want to run virtual machines (on something like VMWare or VirtualBox) to *really* test multi-machine stuff. However, I also develop for multiple machines every day (we have an array of app servers, an array of background worker servers, e-commerce servers, cache stores and front proxies—and I still just develop on *one* virtual machine that has all that stuff running on it. Provided you make hostnames and ports configurable for everything, there's not much difference between localhost port 9000 and some.server.tld port 8080. Actually running all the VMs on a single computer would likely be painful, both in terms of system resources and complexity.

There are tools to help with setting up VMs with similar or the same configurations too. Take a look at http://vagrantup.com/ and also http://babushka.me/.

Just my $0.02.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to be clear, you're suggesting running it all on 1 VM but just make sure the hostnames and ports are configured right for being on 1 VM, right?

Comment: Yeah, so your dev config files will have 'localhost' for everything, but your production config will have actual hostnames. As I say, if you *really* want to test multiple machines, run multiple VMs.

Comment: There are tools to help with setting up VMs with similar or the same configurations too. Take a look at http://vagrantup.com/ and also http://babushka.me/.